# Filter on date range with dynamic rest

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, dynamic-rest

I am using django, drf and dynamic rest. I would like to filter on a date range, but there is [no documentation](https://dynamic-rest.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#default-filtering-of-related-objects) for it.

How can we specify a date range in the url for dynamic rest?

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question:

```
/api/v1/operation/?filter{date.range}[]=2012-01-01T00:00:00Z&filter{date.range}[]=2013-01-01T00:00:00Z
```

This will apply a `range` filter on the  `date` field on the related model.

The date format is as supported by `DateTimeField`, via [parse_datetime](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/utils/dateparse/):

```
datetime_re = re.compile(
    r'(?P<year>\d{4})-(?P<month>\d{1,2})-(?P<day>\d{1,2})'
    r'[T ](?P<hour>\d{1,2}):(?P<minute>\d{1,2})'
    r'(?::(?P<second>\d{1,2})(?:\.(?P<microsecond>\d{1,6})\d{0,6})?)?'
    r'(?P<tzinfo>Z|[+-]\d{2}(?::?\d{2})?)?$'
)
```

(which is basically an extension of [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601))

I do not think this datetime format is configurable at the django level. Seems to be a different thing than [DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#datetime-input-formats).